# Is there a way to display data from firestore into an select in a materialize modal?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, materialize

I am trying to display data, stored in Firestore, in a select list within a materialize modal. The code I have created for making the modal is:

```
      <button class="btn red darken-2 z-depth-0 admin modal-trigger" data-target="modal-delete" style="display: none;"> Slett øvelse </button>


      <div id="modal-delete" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <h4> Slett øvelse </h4><br />
            <select id="delete-form" class="" style="display: block;">

            </select>
            <button class="btn red darken-2 z-depth-0" style="margin-top: 5px;"> Slett </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This works an a modal with an empty list shows up and if I put an option tag under select, it also works. But I am trying to make data stored in Firestore display so the user can then choose one item and the delete it. 
I tried something like this:

```
function renderGuides(doc){
  let option = documents.createElement('option');
  let title = document.createElement('span');


  option.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id)
  title.textContent = doc.data().title;

  li.appendChild(title); // Line 74

  deleteForm.appendChild(li);
}

db.collection('øvelser').get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => { // Line 80
    renderGuides(doc); // Line 81 
  });
});
```

This does not work and this error code show up:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: li is not defined
    at renderGuides (index.js:74)
    at index.js:81
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at index.js:80
```

I have tried multiple solutions but none seems to work. What is the easiest way to make this work?

And after that, I was planning on adding this to delete the selected data in the list, but since I can't make them even display, I can nether test if this works:

```
 cross.textContent = 'x';

li.appendChild(cross);

cross.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  let id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
  db.collection('øvelser').doc(id).delete();
}
```

And I was just wondering if this should work?

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! This error it's self explanatory. you are not defining what is "li" in your code. I'm asuming "li" is the list/array of object readed form Firebase but I don't see were you are defining it. Also I would recommend yout to [push and pop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp) items from your array in JS instead of append